# Classification of algebraic groups of the types $^1\! A_{n-1}$ and $^2\! A_{n-1}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

This seemingly elementary question was asked in Mathematics StackExchange.com: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4779592/37763.
It got upvotes, but no answers or comments, and so I ask it here.

Let $G$ be a simply connected absolutely simple algebraic group
of one of the types $^1{\sf A}_{n-1}$ (inner) or $^2{\sf A}_{n-1}$
(outer) over a field $k$. All such groups are described on page 55
of Tits, Classification of algebraic semisimple groups,
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math. 9 (Boulder), 1966, pp. 33-61.
The descriptions are as follows:

Type $^1{\sf A}_{n-1}$:
Special linear group ${\rm SL}_m(D)$, where $D$ is a central division algebra of degree $d$ over $k$, and $n=md$.

Type $^2{\sf A}_{n-1}$:
Special unitary group ${\rm SU}_m(D,h)$, where $D$ is a central division algebra of degree $d$
over a quadratic extension $K$ of $k$ with an involution of the second kind $\sigma\colon D\to D$ such that
$k=\{x\in K\ |\ x^\sigma=x\}$,
$$h\colon D^m\times D^m\to D$$
is a nondegenerate hermitian form relative to $\sigma$, and $n=md$.

> **Question.** I am looking for a down-to-earth proof
> that all such groups are indeed of the form either ${\rm SL}_m(D)$ or  ${\rm SU}_m(D,h)$.
> (For me, the Book of Involutions is not down-to-earth.)

I know that my group becomes ${\rm SL}_n(\bar k)$ over an algebraic closure $\bar k$ of $k$.

Comment: Is Section 24.f of Milne's Algebraic Groups not down-to-earth?

Comment: As usual, Milne's Algebraic Groups is very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried Chapter 17, section 17.1 from Springer's book on algebraic groups? I believe that is as down-to-earth as it can get, and it is certainly rather detailed.